Program only lets me play game once
I have this matching number game here. basically when you press the form the numbers start to generate randomly. you click the labels to stop them and try to match them. the game should play when the numbers are stopped and you press the form itself but only lets me play one round any ideas?

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace VS_assignment
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Random random = new Random();
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        private bool label1Stopped = false;
        private bool label2Stopped = false;
        private bool label3Stopped = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeLabels();
            InitializeTimer();
        }

        private void InitializeLabels()
        {
            // Set labels to display "?"
            label1.Text = "?";
            label2.Text = "?";
            label3.Text = "?";

            // Attach click event handler to labels
            label1.Click += label_Click;
            label2.Click += label_Click;
            label3.Click += label_Click;
        }

        private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label label = sender as Label;
            if (label != null)
            {
                label.Tag = true; // Set Tag to true to indicate stopped
                if (label == label1)
                    label1Stopped = true;
                else if (label == label2)
                    label2Stopped = true;
                else if (label == label3)
                    label3Stopped = true;

                CheckAndUpdateLabel4();
            }
        }

        private void InitializeTimer()
        {
            timer.Interval = 600;
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateLabel(label1);
            UpdateLabel(label2);
            UpdateLabel(label3);
        }

        private void UpdateLabel(Label label)
        {
            if (!(label.Tag != null && (bool)label.Tag == true))
            {
                label.Text = random.Next(10).ToString();
            }
        }

        private void CheckAndUpdateLabel4()
        {
            if (label1Stopped && label2Stopped && label3Stopped)
            {
                int[] values = { int.Parse(label1.Text), int.Parse(label2.Text), int.Parse(label3.Text) };
                if (values.All(x => x == values[0]))
                {
                    // All numbers are the same, increment label4
                    label4.Text = (int.Parse(label4.Text.Trim('$')) + bet).ToString("$0");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Numbers are different, decrement label4
                    label4.Text = (int.Parse(label4.Text.Trim('$')) - bet).ToString("$0");
                }

                // Reset stop flags
                label1Stopped = false;
                label2Stopped = false;
                label3Stopped = false;
            }
        }

        int bet = 1;

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bet = 1;
        }

        private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bet = 2;
        }

        private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Stop the timer if it's running
            timer.Stop();

            // Reset all labels
            label1Stopped = false;
            label2Stopped = false;
            label3Stopped = false;

            // Start a new round when the form is clicked
            StartNewRound();
        }

        private void StartNewRound()
        {
            // Start the timer
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
}

I have the numbers working properly and the points incrementing and decrementing based on the radial button chosen however when i press the form it does nothing the second time around

I got it!
I basically made a label reset state and called that along with a start new round in form click.
 private void ResetLabels()
 {
     label1.Tag = null;
     label2.Tag = null;
     label3.Tag = null;
 }

private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Reset the tag of all labels
    ResetLabels();

    // Stop the timer if it's running
    timer.Stop();

    // Start a new round when the form is clicked
    StartNewRound();
}

